# Upon clicking one absent button, all other absent buttons get selected. I just want to select only one absent button at a time

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

This is before selecting an absent button
[image: This is before selecting an absent button]

This is after selecting an absent button
[image: This is after selecting an absent button]

This is my code in vuejs:

```
<b-button pill variant="outline-secondary" :class="{ absent: showAbsent }"  @click="markAttendance"   >A</b-button>    

methods: {
    markAttendance() {
      this.showAbsent = true;
    }
  }

    .absent { background-color: red; }
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're just duplicating the b-button instead of creating unique approach for multiple buttons.

You may need to enhance your data to create an array of attendees like `attendees: [{absence: false, name: "John Doe"}...]`, and then loop/iterate the attendees like `<b-button v-for="(atende, a) in atendees" :key="a" :class="{absent: atendee.absence}" @click="atendees[a].absence=!atendees[a].absence">`.

Vue has a concise documentation, you may [read more about loops here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/?#Conditionals-and-Loops).

Comment: Not sure why the OP is ignoring your answer, but you got 1+ from me. Thank you for passing on this information.